# Kendo DropDownList - how to manually select an item?

Tags: kendo-ui

I use the dropDownList for one of my grid's columns. I try to maually select an item after the data was loaded:

```
columns: [
{
      field: "SomeName", title: "Name",
      editor: function (container, options) {
            $scope.options = {
                    dataSource: someSource,
                    dataTextField: "Name",
                    dataValueField: "ID",
                    dataBound: function (e) {
                        e.sender.select(2);
                    }
            }
            var editor = $('<input kendo-drop-down-list k-options="options" required  data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
                         .appendTo(container);
      }
}]
```

but nothing happend, the data returnd by the server was:

```
[{"ID":2,"Name":"abc"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, I figured it out:

```
e.sender.value(2);
```